# How to do an if/else in HAML without repeating indented code

Tags: ruby, haml

Depending on if a user is signed in or not, I'd like to print a different kind of %body-tag.

This is how I currently do it:

```
- if defined? @user
  %body(data-account="#{@user.account}")
    %h1 Welcome
    -# all my content
- else
  %body
    %h1 Welcome
    -# all my content
```

As you can see there's a lot of duplicated code in there. How can I eliminate this? I already tried the following:

```
- if defined? @user
  %body(data-account="#{@user.account}")
- else
  %body
  %h1 Welcome
  -# all my content
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work since HAML interprets it as if the %h1 and the content is part of the else-statement, which of course they aren't.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I run in this problem all the time, so I can't imagine there isn't a simple solution for it.

Comment: Is the 2nd `%body` supposed to be inside the `else` or not?

Comment: Yes, it should. But the %h1 and content shouldn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
!!!
 - @user = "jed" #=> stubbing out an instance
%html
  %head
    - string = defined?(@user) ? "#{@user}" : nil #=> for demo only, wrap this in a helper method
    %title{'data-account' => string}
  %body
    =yield
```

Comment: Marc - without seeing the other answer by @bahabil before i posted, his will work too, or as you asked about not setting the data-account attribute when @user.nil?, this will do that, it just wont put the key in if string is nil. string could be a helper method call in your view helper.

Comment: Thanks, works great! The parentheses for the defined?-method actually solved the problem I encountered with bhaibel's answer.

Comment: Where can I define the helper method?

Comment: @Lokesh in the application helper or the associated helper for the controller: http://mixandgo.com/blog/the-beginner-s-guide-to-rails-helpers

Answer (score 13):

I don't think that you can avoid the indentation issue, because of the way HAML autoassigns the "end" statement, but you can instead push the if statement into the body tag itself -

```
%body{:data_account => (defined? @user ? @user.account : nil)}
```

as opposed to

```
%body(data-account="#{@user.account}")
```

Not super-pretty, but less ugly than repeating the entire block!

Comment: I can't imagine HAML having an elegant solution for such a common use-case. If it's really the case I might have to consider moving to regular HTML again.

Anyway, thanks for your suggestion. Is it possible to omit the 'data-account'-attribute altogether if @user isn't defined?

Comment: This code'll do that - setting :data_account => nil (which this does, indirectly) will lead HAML to ignore the attribute and generate a plain body tag.

Comment: The code returns the following:
<body data-account='expression'>

So instead of executing the expression and return its value, it just displays the word 'expression'. (And no, the @user.account != 'expression')

Comment: Turns out the solution was to use parentheses for the defined? method.

Answer (score 4):

HAML's elegant solution is helpers

```
class ApplicationHelper...

  def body_for_user(user, &blk)
    return content_tag(:body, :'data-account' => user.account, &blk) if user
    content_tag(:body, &blk)
  end

end
```

The ternary operators described above are more than sufficient for this particular situation, but for more complex things, break out the helpers.

Oh, to use this, in your view change `%body(...)` to `= body_for_user @user do`

Comment: I forgot to mention it explicitly in my opening post, but I'm not using Rails but Sinatra, which doesn't have the content_tag method. I can probably mimic it, but I rather keep it as simple as possible.

Thanks for the suggestion though. It will be useful in my Rails projects.

Answer (score 1):

Write a helper like this:

```
def body_attributes
  {}.tap do |hash|
    hash[:data] = {}
    hash[:data][:account] = @user.account if @user
    # add any other attributes for the body tag here
  end
end
```

Then call the helper from the body element:

```
%body{ body_attributes }
  %h1 Welcome
  -# all my content
```

Comment: See http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#attribute_methods for more information about attribute methods.

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, but this just returns:
<body body_attributes>

Comment: Updated example. You need curly braces around the method name (I used parens).

Answer (score 1):

For anybody looking for an answer to the Ruby if/else issue with HAML this is how I worked around it:

```
%tr{ id: (line_item == @current_item) ? "current_item" : nil }
  %td= button_to '-', decrement_line_item_path(line_item), method: :put, remote: true
  %td #{line_item.quantity}&times;
  %td= line_item.product.title
  %td.item_price= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually set the @@menu variable at the controller, then in bootstrap-enabled layout.haml I define:

```
  ...
  %body
    .navbar.navbar-fixed-top
      .navbar-inner
        .container
          %a.btn.btn-navbar{"data-target" => ".nav-collapse", "data-toggle" => "collapse"}
            %span.icon-bar
            %span.icon-bar
            %span.icon-bar
          %a.brand{:href => "/"} AwesomeApp
          .nav-collapse
            %ul.nav
              %li{:class => @@menu == 'home' && :active}
                %a{:href => "/"} Home
              %li{:class => @@menu == 'about' && :active}
                %a{:href => "/about"} About
              %li{:class => @@menu == 'contact' && :active}
                %a{:href => "/contact"} Contact
```

when I set @@menu to 'about' it will render:

```
  <body>
    <div class='navbar navbar-fixed-top'>
      <div class='navbar-inner'>
        <div class='container'>
          <a class='btn btn-navbar' data-target='.nav-collapse' data-toggle='collapse'>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          </a>
          <a class='brand' href='/'>AwesomeApp</a>
          <div class='nav-collapse'>
            <ul class='nav'>
              <li>
                <a href='/'>Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class='active'>
                <a href='/about'>About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='/contact'>Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see 'about' class being applied...are you sure this is after you set @@menu variable?

Comment: @v_mitchell: there is "@@menu == 'about' && :active" ternary operator which returns :active if @@menu is equal to 'about' string.