# Haml: If statement inside attribute declaration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to put a conditional for a style attribute. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3460852/538471) something like this should be possible:

```
.hello{:style => (true ? 'color: green' : 'color: red;')}
```

But for me the style attribute doesn't get outputted at all. Did things change in Haml? I rather not create a helper for such simple logic.

Comment: Your code should work (and does for me when I test it). You say the attribute doesn’t get rendered at all–that would happen if the value evaluated to `false` or `nil`.

Comment: @matt: Works for me too in the console only

Comment: What does your real code look like? (I assume that you don’t really test the literal `true` for truthiness).

Comment: @matt: I did yes, I tried the exact same code that worked in the console.

Comment: Should definitely work. Take a step back. Are you editing the correct file? Is any caching involved? Do you have multiple servers running and are visiting the wrong one in the browser? HTH

Comment: @Raffael: I was trying it in a view that was injected with the deface gem. Putting the same code in another view makes it work. Must be a deface bug.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the easy route out and add a line:

```
- color = true ? 'color: green' : 'color: red;'
.hello{:style => color}
```

The even easier way is to add a further class and control it from the css/javascript as needs be:

```
- success_class = true ? 'success' : 'failed'
.hello{:class => success_class}
```

This would give you `<div class='hello success'></div>`

---

Edit: the ternary seems to work too, though

```
require 'haml'
# => true
str = ".hello{:class => true ? 'green' : 'red' }"
# => ".hello{:class => true ? 'green' : 'red' }"
Haml::Engine.new(str).render

# => "<div class='green hello'></div>\n"
str = ".hello{:style => true ? 'color:green' : 'color:red' }"
# => ".hello{:style => true ? 'color:green' : 'color:red' }"
Haml::Engine.new(str).render
# => "<div class='hello' style='color:green'></div>\n"
```

Comment: If that's the only way to do it, I will definitely create a helper

Comment: @dan-klasson I just added some more checks.

Comment: Ok that's weird, it works in the console for me too, but not in the actual view