# How to write if condition inside the checkbox in haml?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am a newbie in haml and I have learnt basics of haml and I am now able to convert a simple html form in haml but I am stuck in a little problem. I am converting this code in haml but not able to do it. I am trying from last 3 hours. I have also google it but not found any usable answer
[Haml: If statement inside attribute declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446554/haml-if-statement-inside-attribute-declaration)

I am converting this code

```
<input class="prime campaign_chkbox" data-type="payrolloption" id="<%= element['id'] %>" type="checkbox" <%if element['payrolloption']==1 %> checked <%end%> >
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it

```
%input.prime.campaign_chkbox{:type=>"checkbox", "data-type" => 'payrolloption',:id=>"#{element['id']}", :checked => ("#{element['payrolloption']}"=='1' ? true : false)  }
```

Comment: You don't need the ternary operator as it is basically saying "if true, true else false". Just do `checked: "#{element['payrolloption']=='1'}"`.